Need help in plotting a graph calculated with ``NIntegrate``
This is my Mathematica code,
Get["EDCRGTCcode.m", Path -> {NotebookDirectory[]}]
n = 5;
coord = {t, y1, y2, y3, z};
met = DiagonalMatrix[(L^2 Exp[2 A[z]])/
    z^2 {-g[z, B], 1, Exp[B^2 z^2], Exp[B^2 z^2] , 1/g[z, B]}];
RGtensors[met, coord]
A[z_] = -a z^2;
g[z_, B_] = 
  1 - Integrate[z^3 Exp[-B^2 z^2 - 3 A[z]], {z, 0, z}]/
   Integrate[z^3 Exp[-B^2 z^2 - 3 A[z]], {z, 0, zh}];
csq = (-(-gdd[[1, 1]]) gdd[[3, 3]] gdd[[4, 4]]) /. z -> zs;
 L = 1; a = 0.15; zh = 1;
t[z1_?NumericQ, z2_?NumericQ, B_, pm_] := 
 pm NIntegrate[
   Sqrt[ (csq gdd[[5, 5]])/(
    gdd[[1, 1]] (gdd[[3, 3]] gdd[[4, 4]] gdd[[1, 1]] - csq))], {z, z2,
     zh, z1}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive", Exclusions -> {z - zh == 0}]
plot = Quiet@
   ParametricPlot[{{z1, Re[t[z1, 0.2, 0.2, 1]]}, {z1, 
      Re[t[z1, 0.2, 0.2, -1]]}}, {z1, 1, 2}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Blue}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/2];
Show[plot]

The plot is coming up like this.

Though it explicitly depends on $z_2$ and $B$, there is no change in the plot behaviour as I'm changing the $z_2$ and $B$ values.
This is the output for $z_2=0.2$ and $B=0.2$,
In[12]:= Table[{{z1, Re[t[z1, 0.2, 0.2, 1]]}, {z1, 
   Re[t[z1, 0.2, 0.2, -1]]}}, {z1, 1, 2, 1/4}]

Out[12]= {{{1, 0.}, {1, 0.}}, {{5/4, 0.}, {5/4, 0.}}, {{3/2, 0.}, {3/
   2, 0.}}, {{7/4, 0.}, {7/4, 0.}}, {{2, 0.}, {2, 0.}}}

This is the output for $z_2=1.5$ and $B=0.1$,
In[13]:= Table[{{z1, Re[t[z1, 1.5, 0.1, 1]]}, {z1, 
   Re[t[z1, 1.5, 0.1, -1]]}}, {z1, 1, 2, 1/4}]

Out[13]= {{{1, 0.}, {1, 0.}}, {{5/4, 0.}, {5/4, 0.}}, {{3/2, 0.}, {3/
   2, 0.}}, {{7/4, 0.}, {7/4, 0.}}, {{2, 0.}, {2, 0.}}}

Don't know why; all the values are coming 0.
Could anybody help me find where I'm making a mistake, or is there any error in the code?

When Plot doesn't work the first thing I try is replacing that with Table which will show me some of the values. That usually exposes why it isn't working. Can you edit your post to show the output after replacing ParametricPlot[...] with Table[{{z1,Re[t[z1,0.2,0.2,1]]},{z1,Re[t[z1,0.2,0.2,-1]]}},{z1,1,2,1/4}] with your current values for za2andBand then with the changed values forz2andB? If the step size of 1/2 in the Table` doesn't expose the problem then it may need a different step size.

Thanks for your suggestion. I'll edit my post.

Thanks for the edit. So Plot really is getting zeros.  Another edit t[z1_?NumericQ,z2_?NumericQ, B_, pm_]:=(Print[pm*Sqrt[(csq gdd[[5,5]])/(gdd[[1,1]](gdd[[3,3]] gdd[[4,4]] gdd[[1,1]]-csq))]];pm NIntegrate[Sqrt[(csq gdd[[5,5]])/(gdd[[1,1]](gdd[[3,3]] gdd[[4,4]]gdd[[1,1]]-csq))],{z,z2,zh,z1},Method->"LocalAdaptive",Exclusions->{z-zh==0}]) to show what NIntegrate is really getting. Might tell people where you are getting EDCRGTCcode.m so they think they can trust getting that. Can't tell, don't know, maybe should be A[z_]:= and g[z_,B_]:= instead of just A[z_]= and g[z_,B_]=

I've tried it, but a similar thing is happening. EDCRGTCcode.m is a package for GR-related calculations.
